# EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: Unable to delete row, SQL Syntax error

Tags: entity-framework-core, mariadb, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

I am using an ASP.NET Core Web API with Entity Framework Core (pomelo). I have a MariaDB database. I use Swagger UI to explore my API, as per the template. When I try to use it to delete a row, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURNING 1' at line 3
>
> at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 894
> at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 37
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.InitAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 483
> at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 357
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 350
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The delete should be handled here in my controller and repository, like this:

```
    [HttpDelete("alertId")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAlert(int alertId)
    {
        var alert = await _dataRepository.GetAlertAsync(alertId);

        if (alert is null)
        {
            return NotFound("Alert not found");
        }

        await _dataRepository.DeleteAlertAsync(alert);

        return NoContent(); 
    }
```

and this

```
public class AlertRepository (IrtsContext context) : IDataRepositoryAlerts
{
    readonly IrtsContext _alertContext = context;

    public async Task DeleteAlertAsync(Alert entity)
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            _alertContext.Remove(entity);
            await _alertContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand this. I believe it is my `dbContext` that handles the "saving the entity changes". How can I have a SQL syntax error? I cannot find "Returning 1" anywhere in my code.

I have tried deleting the row manually in my database. That works.
All other operations (GET, POST and PUT) work just fine.

I have tried running this with holding points to see where the error occurs but everything seems to execute without issue.

I am grateful for any hints. I am obviously very new to this ;)

Edit: MariaDB version 11.2.2
Edit2: This is my Alert class:

```
    public partial class Alert
{
    public int AlertId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Zeitpunkt { get; set; }
    public string? Quelle { get; set; }
    public string? AlertStatus { get; set; }
    public string? AlertTyp { get; set; }
    public string? BetroffeneSysteme { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vorfall> Vorfalls { get; set; } = new List<Vorfall>();
    }
```

and this is its entity configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Alert>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.AlertId).HasName("PRIMARY");
    entity
        .ToTable("alert")
        .HasCharSet("utf8mb4")
        .UseCollation("utf8mb4");
    entity.Property(e => e.AlertId)
        .HasColumnType("int(11)")
        .HasColumnName("AlertID");
    entity.Property(e => e.AlertStatus).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.AlertTyp).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.BetroffeneSysteme).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.Quelle).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.Zeitpunkt).HasColumnType("datetime");
});
```

edit3: I found the parameterized query. It goes thus:
[The error in the log with sql query]

Edit 4: copying the query into workbench gives the following error:

[image: sql]

It appears that the problem really is the "RETURNING 1" and I must admit I have no idea what it is for. Is there a way to remove it? I have found no way to edit the EF queries themselves. Alternatively I might need to try a different database.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: MariaDB version 11.2.2

Comment: EF should log the parameterized query that it attempted. Are you able to see that in the console logging while attempting the delete? It may also be helpful to see the `Alert` class and any EntityModel configurations you have for that class.

Comment: If you copy the delete query from your log screen shot, replace the @p0 with the id of the alert you want to delete, and run that manually, does THAT work?

Comment: are you sure it is 11.2.2? "RETURNING" is supported from 10.5.0

Comment: you could try to set version in the code to (10, 0, 1) and try again

Comment: can you execute a `select @@version` on your db to confirm the version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your investigation, I suspect your DB version is older than you think. You could try adding the `ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)` to your EF core MySql configuration. See if that influences EF core to write SQL that in understandable to your DB version? It would look something like this when you are configuring services:

```
Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
{
    //...your other configs
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("or however you get the connection string...");
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});
```

You can also try setting the version explicitly like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseMySql(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("how ever you get this"),
            mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(10, 0, 40, ServerType.MariaDb)
        )
    );
```

Use which ever version you have, though

Comment: Ah yes. I was indeed mistaken about the server version. Egg is on my face. Two different mysql servers running concurrently without my noticing and I am in fact connected to MySQL 8.0.36. I used your Serverversion.Autodetect but this does not seem to help. My EF version is 8.0.2. Should that not be compatible?  Thank you all very much!

Comment: hmm, could be too old for the MySql package to support? You can try setting the db version explicitly. I updated the answer a bit

Comment: And we have a winner! Thank you very much ArcherBird and others! :)